# Changing the bash function to awk

Tags: shell, unix, awk

My team has designed below function. It is in Bash. I have to call this function for the file which has hundreds of thousands of records. This is taking too much time. Can anyone of you please suggest me to change the below function into awk?

```
 data_mask() {

  col_val=$1
  l_ret_str=""
  l_an=0
  l_lp=0
  l_mod=0
  absnum=0
  austart=65
  auend=90
  aclsize=26
  alstart=97
  alend=122
  nstart=48
  nend=57
  nclsize=10

  l_lp=`expr length "$col_val"`
  if [[ $l_lp -ne 0 ]]; then
    for i in `eval "echo {1..$l_lp}"`
    do
      single_char=$(SUBSTR "$col_val" $i)
      ascii_num_val=$(ASCII "$single_char")
      l_mod=$((l_mod+ascii_num_val))
    done

    l_mod=$((l_mod % nclsize))

    for i in `eval "echo {1..$l_lp}"`
    do
      single_char=$(SUBSTR "$col_val" $i)
      ascii_num_val=$(ASCII "$single_char")
      l_an=$ascii_num_val
      tempvar=$((l_an - l_lp - l_mod - i))
      absnum=$(ABS $tempvar)
      if [[ $l_an -ge $austart && $l_an -le $auend ]]; then
        tempmodval=$((absnum % aclsize))
        tempasciival=$((austart + tempmodval))
        l_ret_str=$l_ret_str$(CHR $tempasciival)
      elif [[ $l_an -ge $alstart && $l_an -le $alend ]]; then
        tempmodval=$((absnum % aclsize))
        tempasciival=$((alstart + tempmodval))
        l_ret_str=$l_ret_str$(CHR $tempasciival)
      elif [[ $l_an -ge $nstart && $l_an -le $nend ]]; then
        tempmodval=$((absnum % nclsize))
        tempasciival=$((nstart + tempmodval))
        l_ret_str=$l_ret_str$(CHR $tempasciival)
      else
        tempmodval=$((absnum % nclsize))
        tempasciival=$((austart + tempmodval))
        l_ret_str=$l_ret_str$(CHR $tempasciival)
      fi

    done
  fi
  echo "$l_ret_str"
}
```

I am calling this function by using below login. I have to call it for specific column. That column is entered by the user. So I am splitting the string into 3 parts.

```
  while read p; do

  if [[ $line -le $skip_line ]]; then
    echo "$p" >> $outputfile
  else
    pre_str=`echo $p | cut -d'|' -f1-$((colnum - 1))`
    column_value=`echo $p | cut -d'|' -f$colnum`
    post_str=`echo $p | cut -d'|' -f$((colnum + 1))-$totalcol`
    echo "column_value=$column_value"
    maskvalue=$(data_mask "$column_value")
    #echo $pre_str"|"$maskvalue"|"$post_str >> $outputfile
#    awk -v col=2 'BEGIN { FS=OFS="|" } col<=NF { $col = data_mask(" $col ") } 1' $temp_outputfile >>123.txt
     awk -v col=3 'BEGIN { FS=OFS="|" } col<=NF { $col = $maskvalue; print }' $temp_outputfile >123.txt
#     awk -F"|" -vOFS="|" 'NR==1{$3=100} {print}' file
  fi

  line=$((line + 1))

  done < $file
```

Could anyone of you please suggest me what to do for optimization?

Comment: Could you please provide sample input and expected output we could help in creating a new or editing this one itself then.

Comment: Seriously? Again, no sample input and expected output?  Are we back to FUNCTION being an awk function or a shell function? Why don't you simply provide a definition for FUNCTION so we have a clue what it is you're trying to do? @shrutisharma please discuss [ask] with Onkar and read the previous feedback you've received on your questions so you guys can get the most effective help from this community.

Comment: @shrutisharma.... Now help me.

Comment: I see that you used @EdMorton 's script from his 5-year-old answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15769957/apply-a-function-to-one-column-only-with-a-variable-location

Comment: ya.. I used because my problem was of similar types. But performance has not been improved. It is taking 4hrs to mask 1 lakh data. Now I have updated the question. Could you please suggest me on the same.

Comment: This question has now been completely rewritten to be totally unrelated to the accepted answer. Please put it back so the answer at least makes some kind of sense wrt the question for others looking at this in future.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
awk -v col=3 'col<=NF { $col = "FUNCTION(" $col ")" } 1' file
```

You can change separator to pipe easily:

```
awk -v col=3 'BEGIN { FS=OFS="|" } col<=NF { $col = "FUNCTION(" $col ")" } 1' file
```

This should work in any AWK.

Comment: Thanks a lot @AndriyMakukha

Comment: This is working when function receiving the argument in parameter. otherwise it is giving error function not recognized.

Comment: Which function?

Comment: my function name is data_mask(). I am using below command. It dint work.   awk -v col=2 'BEGIN { FS=OFS="|" } col<=NF { $col = (data_mask $col) } 1' $temp_outputfile >>123.txt

Comment: Moreover my function receives value of that column.... here in awk I think we are passing column number. Could you please help me on the same.

Comment: We have to call this function. data_mask() {

  col_val=$1
}  we are receiving value in col_val.

Comment: I don't understand which function you are talking about. Is it an AWK function? Your and my script are only adding the function name to the output. It doesn't run any function. Where is your function defined? In bash? In other AWK script? It's not clear.

Comment: It is defined in bash. we are calling bash function from awk.

Comment: See here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43699983/how-to-call-a-user-defined-function-from-awk

Comment: Thanks @AndriyMakukha . But actaully it dint work. My scenario is, my user defined function name is data_mask(). I have to call it from awk for any column entered by user. this function takes value of that column, not the column number. Could you please provide the command.

Comment: I mean, you cannot call a Bash function from AWK easily.

Comment: ok..Thanks.. Any other way? right now we are storing the value of that column in variable. then we are passing the value to function. it is taking lot of time. pre_str=`echo $p | cut -d'|' -f1-$((colnum - 1))`
    column_value=`echo $p | cut -d'|' -f$colnum`
    post_str=`echo $p | cut -d'|' -f$((colnum + 1))-$totalcol`
    echo "column_value=$column_value"
     maskvalue=$(data_mask "$column_value")
    echo $pre_str"|"$maskvalue"|"$post_str >> $outputfile
  here col_num is no given by user and data_mask is funtion. any better way for this?

Comment: I have updated the question. Can I replace that code through some efficient way?

Comment: @OnkarTiwari, if you need performance, I would recommend not to use Bash for processing text files. If you can, just rewrite your function in faster language, like AWK or Python.

Comment: Thanks you @Andriy . I have updated the question. Could you please help me on the same.

Comment: @OnkarTiwari, I suggest you to post this question to https://codereview.stackexchange.com – the website created for this kind of questions.

Comment: Thank you @AndriyMakukha .I will do the same.